# How to make an arbitrary large number of variables be treated as factors

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I have a large amount of variables that I must treat as categorical although they are represented numerically. For one variable I know I can use

```
train$var1 = as.factor(train$var1)
```

But how can I apply the same for as many variables as I want?

Comment: If you want to apply it to _all_ columns (variables), you can do `train[] <- lapply(train, as.factor)`

Comment: Oh, seems obvious! sorry, I am still very knew to r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply it to *all* columns (variables), you can do

```
train[] <- lapply(train, as.factor)
```

or for a subset of columns (for example 3 to 10) use

```
train[3:10] <- lapply(train[3:10], as.factor)
```